# Trigger event when text length overflows a userform textbox

Tags: excel, vba, scrollbar, userform

I have a `UserForm` with a `TextBox` (among other controls). `MultiLine` and `WordWrap` are enabled. When I enter text into the `TextBox`, the line wraps at the right end of the line, and continues to do so till the `TextBox` is full, at which point a vertical scrollbar appears. All this is normal and works.

I wish to detect when the box is full so that I can trigger a macro.

I thought of using a 'change' event for the TextBox, to check if the vertical scrollbar is active, but I cannot find away to detect whether the scrollbar is visible. If I could detect this, I could use the activation of the scrollbar to achieve the desired end goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the Textbox's Height is stable and you do not need to change it.
Then you could try the following.
Insert text until your TextBox is full and count the visible lines.
For this example I'll guess they are 5.

Then in the Change event of the TextBox put the following.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If Me.TextBox1.LineCount > 5 Then
        'fire your macro here
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Not had a chance to check yet but it looks ideal. Will certainly 'accept' once I have had a chance to try it out. Thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: It would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: Great thanks. Never thought of that approach. I have 'accepted' the answer. One slight thing that came up. The code works perfectly while the user is typing into the textbox but throws an error when data is loaded into the box because the focus isn't in the relevant control. Easy to get around. The code now looks like this...[code] Private Sub TextBox8_Change() Me.TextBox8.SetFocus If Me.TextBox8.LineCount > 10 Then 'fire your macro here End If – 
RannochRob     Apologies, not having any luck with the dropdown codes...